# JPA - Pagination, count(id) is slow

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, informix

I have a REST App that has JPA query to fetch allObjects

Below query runs to get me resultset for my getAll operations. It takes 49 sec on my DEV box for 32M rows in myTable.

```
select
    SKIP 200 FIRST 20 *
from
    myTable table0_ 
order by
    id desc
```

My issue, however, is with `count(id)` query that JPA automatically runs to get data for pagination. This one is very slow and took 4 min.

```
select count(id) as col_0_0_ 
from myTable table0_
```

Also, `Id` is the primary key on the table, and the query itself directly on DB is taking 14s. Not sure if something in Hibernate is slowing it down.

DB is Informix if that makes any difference.

Comment: counting rows is never fast and rdbms dependent.

Comment: @Antoniossss Agreed. But Spring JPA does that internally for Pagination metadata. Also, I am assuming since it is employing an index, it should be faster and Full Scan Search. Also, as I said before since same query is faster if run directly on DB, something in Hibernate is making it slower

Comment: Since the `id` column is the primary key, it presumably has a NOT NULL constraint and there is a unique index on it.  Can you persuade JPA to run `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(id)`?  Have you run UPDATE STATISTICS on `myTable`?  If so, what options did you use?  Which version of Informix, running on which platform (o/s and version)?  Is the table volatile, by any chance — that is, does the number of rows in it vary drastically?

Comment: The significance of `COUNT(*)` vs `COUNT(id)` is that the latter has to count the rows with non-null values for `id`, whereas the former is a metadata lookup on the number of rows in the table.  Have you checked that the indexes are OK (with `oncheck`)?  Is there any danger that a disk drive is beginning to fail?  (Probably not, but funnier things have been known to slow systems down.). How wide are the rows?  Are there any BLOB, CLOB, BYTE or TEXT columns in the table?

Comment: What is the question?